# Build a .lib with the Intel C++ compiler and use with app in VC++?

Tags: c++, performance, visual-c++, compiler-construction, intel

I'm using VC++ 2012 to compile a solution with 2 projects. The main library is a Class Library project which simply outputs a .lib file, and the second is an Application, which uses the compiled library.

This library is used for high-performance math in my app, so I was considering switching to the [Intel C++ compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1982178/intel-c-compiler-as-an-alternative-to-microsofts) for this portion of the solution. Is it possible to build a `.lib` with the Intel C++ compiler, and then link to that lib from my VC++ project to finally build my app? Is [this article](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-integrated-performance-primitives-intel-ipp-for-windows-compiling-and-linking-with-microsoft-visual-c-and-intel-c-compilers) describing what I want?

I cannot switch the app project to the Intel Compiler for legal reasons. (Although I have the source code for the app, it is compiled by the client and they use VC++, we are only the authors of the library project)